# How do I extract cell values from column object in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

In Python, printing a column from the spreadsheet just returns

```
<Cell 'File Name' .A000>
```

but what I want is the singular value that is in the cell. I can not figure out from openpyxl's documentation how to do this for the whole column the same way you can a singular cell.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are asking. Are you looking for a single function that returns the values of all the cells in a column?

Comment: you normally iterate by cell to get column values, what is wrong with that approach?

Comment: @J.Owens Yes. Sorry I'm very clueless about everything Python related. I want to express the values in Column A of my spreadsheet as "1,2,3,4" and not <Cell 'Classification'.A1>,<Cell 'Classification'.A2>,<Cell 'Classification'.A3>,<Cell 'Classification'.A4> if that makes sense.

Ultimately I want to do this for two separate columns, and have an if function that would create an array of values from Column A if the corresponding value in column D was equal to zero.

Comment: I believe you're going to have to loop over the cells in the column yourself. I don't think there's a built-in function that does what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer your question but it is better you add some code if you want get help by other people.

Supposing `col` is the variable representing your column and you want to print the first row:

```
print(col[0].value)
```

If you want to do that for all the rows of the column just use a loop: if `l` is the length of your column:

```
for ii in range(0,l):
    print(col[ii].value)
```

If you do not know apriori the length of your column try something like this:

```
for row in tuple(sheetName.rows):
    print(row[yourColumnNumber].value)
```

or try

```
for row in tuple(col.rows):
    print(row[0].value)
```